# Getting property value in ComboBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `comboBox` and it is binded to list (from database, using entity framework). I would like to get an `AdId` of the selected item(object) on `SelectionChanged` of comboBox.

```
public class Ad
{          
    public int AdId { get; set; }
    public string AdContent { get; set; }
}

private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmd = (ComboBox) sender;
    int AdId = cmd.SelectedItem;

    ???????????? I'm stuck here how to get AdId from SelectedItem... tried SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath... didn't work
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cmd.SelectedItem` property of the ComboBox will returns an object, you can cast them to your own business object. and then you can easily access its properties like the following:

```
int AdId = ((Ad)cmd.SelectedItem).AdId ;
string AdContent =  ((Ad)cmd.SelectedItem).AdContent;
```

Answer (score 3):

Set `SelectedValuePath="AdId"`

And get selected value from code as follow,

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmd = (ComboBox) sender;
    int AdId = (int)cmd.SelectedValue;


}
```

[image]

Comment: In this case Selected Value will be of type `Ad`, not int as you expected

Comment: @un-lucky If we set 'SelectedValuePath="AdId"' the result will be int only. it won't return type 'Ad'. I am posting answer after completion of my testing successfully.

Comment: @un-lucky Yes buddy.

Comment: What if he wants another ( 2 or more ) parameters next time?

Comment: In that case he need see SelectedItem

Comment: @un-lucky you should set SelectedValuePath="AdId" and check

Comment: @un-lucky check the screen shot

Comment: @Vijay : looks perfect

Comment: @un-lucky Thanks buddy :-)